# What is wrong with the time format used in TimeManager

Tags: qgis

I have used the TimeManager plugin in Qgis. Trying to set the time layer to animate features

However I have something of the following

[image: Error image]

I believed I have fulfilled format YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.ssssss with 2020-05-10 03:56:02.859499931.  So anybody can enlighten me what is wrong? Hope is not because of wrong typing

The time (originally in sec) is converted by python into datetime format and saved as a csv(delimited text file) and then loaded into qgis

A sample is reproduced here

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Managed to solve my problem... the problem is due to that the time format should be in YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.ssssss but must be in 3 decimal points.